# Visual Studio web deploy to IIS. Warning : An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create File' on '.dll'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis

I am deploying a .NET Core 6 Blazor app to IIS using web deploy. The publish is successful, but I get this error every time. My target framework is `net6.0`.

Why would VS even be attempt to access the .NET 8 SDK? The publish is successful, it just takes longer than other apps that don't throw the warning error, like 20 or 30 seconds as opposed to 5 seconds.

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5):
> Warning : An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create File' on 'RestonRadiology2021.dll'.
> Retrying operation 'Update' on object filePath (Traker\RestonRadiology2021.dll). Attempt 2 of 10.

Comment: 1. VS always uses the latest SDK version it supports. 2. .NET 8 SDK supports .NET 6 development very well. 3. The issue you faced is well known for years and the solution is also clear, https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Jun/20/Locked-Files-When-Publishing-NET-Core-Apps-to-IIS-with-WebDeploy

Comment: This problem should not be an error that occurs when you deploy it for the first time. You can try to recycle the corresponding application pool or  publish the project on IIS as a new website to check if this work for you.